# Python ftplib, missing last 100 lines of a text file

Tags: python, ftplib

I am trying to download a text file using the python interpreter through ftplib. The text file is 18412 lines, but when I download using python, I get only 18312 lines (code below). If I do it manually from the shell, I get the entire file. Can anyone please take a look at the code and see what I am doing wrong.

File on server:

```
wc -l logs
18412 logs
```

Download script:

```
>>> import ftplib
>>> ftp = ftplib.FTP('A.B.C.D')
>>> ftp.login('USER', 'PASS')
'230-User logged in\n230 Your last login was on 2014-12-31 02-14-41.'
>>> f = open('temp', 'wb')
>>> ftp.retrbinary('RETR /rel/logs', f.write)
'226 Transfer complete'
>>> f.close()
```

Downloaded file:

```
wc -l temp
18312 temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ftp.retrlines(...)` to write your file, not `retrbinary` as line breaks may not be reserved like from \r\n, \n to \r or whatever depending on platforms.

`ftp.retrlines()` is referred as ASCII transfer mode, it's better for transferring log file.